# Show and hide directives using buttons with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have three directives that displays different data in my main view.

```
     <div>
        <sales-view></sales-view>
    </div>

     <div>
         <units-view></units-view>
     </div>
```

And a set of buttons like this:

```
     <div class="btn-group">
         <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Sales</button>
         <button class="btn btn-white" type="button">Units</button>
     </div>
```

What I want is to show or hide my directives depending on the user selection, but I dont know how to achive this, I dont know if the logic goes in the controller or in the directive.

Some help will be great, Im stuck with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand your point.I think this simple logic can write directly in template html.And if is going to complex, please use a config map(or getter setter) instead.

```
<!-- edit html -->
<div>
    <sales-view ng-show="showData == 1"></sales-view>
</div>
<div>
    <units-view ng-show="showData == 2"></units-view>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="showData = 1">Sales</button>
    <button class="btn btn-white" type="button" ng-click="showData = 2">Units</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for your time, thank's a lot!!

Just one more thing, how can I make the selected button to change "class" , for example, SALES is my default view and my button is highlighted, so when I click on UNITS sales button remains highlighted ja!

Comment: My pleasure. You can use `ng-class` for auto change class.like <button ng-class="highlighted == 'sales'" type="button" ng-click="highlighted = Sales">Sales</button>.For more detail you can see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass. And further more, when  it's begin complex, please move some logic to controller (or service if other place want to reuse it)

Comment: Thank's a lot!! 

You such a nice person...  :D